# how to convert text to * without any use of input type="password"

Tags: javascript, string, polymer

I wanna use the polymer elements and my problem is that paper-input does not support type="password", so how is it possible to convert my input characters to *

Comment: Take a look [at this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/polymer-dev/o2f6MscUOzQ/LTrAefu6LT8J).

Answer (score 0):

onedit, get new character, add it to a string, delete the character from textbox and add "*".

Answer (score 0):

i am using paper-input with type="password" without issue. how you do it depends on the version of polymer you are using.

from master

```
        <paper-input-decorator
          id="password"
          labelVisible
          floatinglabel
          error="Password must be 8 chars with numbers, letters and punctuation"
          label="Password">
          <input is="core-input" id="passWord" type="password" pattern="^(?=.*\d.*\d)[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%*]{8,}$" required>
        </paper-input-decorator>
```

from 0.4.2

```
        <paper-input
          id="passWord"
          floatinglabel
          pattern="^(?=.*\d.*\d)[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%*]{8,}$" 
          type="password"
          label="Password"
          required>
        </paper-input>
```

i had a post about this right after the change came up and i explain how i used the changes in the answer. [updated to newest version of polymer and input validation is no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447343/updated-to-newest-version-of-polymer-and-input-validation-is-no-longer-working)